# How to know if it is memory leak or not if Mem Usage in Task Manager keep increasing

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, tcpclient, tcplistener

I wrote a small Server class which basically is a TcpListener wrapper and ThreadPool thread spawner.

The threads run Server::ProcessMessage() which does some work sending messages to and fro and then quits at the end of it.

But just before exiting the function, I also call TcpClient.GetStream().Close() and then TcpClient.Close(). I don't use any Mutex or ManualResetEvent WaitHandles.

Tested the Client and Server, everything works except in task manager it shows the Mem Usage keep on increasing on every Server::ProcessMessage(). Even after all Client apps have been disconnected and closed, the Mem Usage is still there, not decreased.

Server is running as a windows service.

How do I know if it is a sign of memory leak or just garbage collector not doing its job (yet)?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I think I found the cause of my "memory leak". I had Console.WriteLine() in my Server::ProcessMessage(). Still it would be helpful if there was an easier way to check for memory problems.

Comment: Nice question. I've a windows service too with increasing mem. usage. I don't know where too look or what too do either.

Comment: Think I found my problem. Moral is.... look harder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using WinDbg with [SoS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) extension to check if [unneeded objects are still referenced in the heap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx). Check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx) also.

You usually start by using `!DumpHeap -type (some-type-or-just-namespace)` to get a list of objects of a certain type (I usually just write the relevant layer's namespace to get a list or objects which I believe might be still in memory).

If you have more than one instance of a certain object, you will need to pick one address which corresponds to the MT for your object, and then call `!gcroot (your-address)` to see what's keeping your object alive.

In most cases, objects are kept alive because one of their methods is registered as an event handler for some other object's event. A good practice is to always detach your event handlers from parent classes once your object is no longer needed.

Comment: Seems like the right way to go, but for now, I am restricted from installing any other software on the machine on which the server is running (production machine). furhermore, the server MUST run on that machine for the application to work...

Comment: @Jake: that might be difficult to test then (with that "specific machine" constraint). But obviously you have a development machine, right? Isn't there any way at all you could run it there? You would also benefit from creating dummy tcp clients which can connect to your test service locally, and send dummy data (not only for functional and memory testing, but also for stress testing under heavier load).

Comment: @Jake: Apart from that, you can go through your code and make sure that each `+=` (handler attachment) has a `-=` counterpart which gets called when cleaning up/disposing. And obviously, all `IDisposable` objects must be disposed after use (and each object which contains an `IDisposable` object, a Timer, or anything similar, must also implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: the server was created to be a proxy between my app and MS Dynamics AX particularly because AX somehow had the constrain that it will only accept queries from the same windows domain. We don't have business authority in that domain to make changes nor have extra license to install AX for dev purposes.

Comment: I had no event handlers in the server, but I did follow your advice of going through all IDisposable. I think the first issue is the forgotten Console.WriteLine.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a webserver, I'd creating a dummy page handler that forces the GC. If the memory will not be freed, the leak suspect could be serious.

Afterward, the real problem is *where* the leak is!